# Magnesium combustion heat

Tags: combustion

When you are going to burn magnesium you need to wait a few seconds before it actually starts to burn. To get to this point it needs a certain amount of energy/heat. How much does it need?

Comment: Ummm, it's not a matter of specific amount, just at least a small bit should get very hot and then reaction gets self-sustaining.